# Fill elements of a list without looping

Tags: r, list, for-loop, vectorization

I am trying not to use a `for` loop to assign values to the elements of a list.

Here, I create an empty list, gives it a length of 20 and name each of the 20 elements.

```
mylist <- list()
length(mylist) <- 20
names(mylist) <- paste0("element", 1:20, sep = "")
```

I want each element of `mylist` to contain samples drawn from a pool of randomly generated numbers denoted as `x`:

```
x <- runif(100, 0, 1)
```

I tried the following codes, which do not get to the desired result:

```
mylist[[]] <- sample(x = x, size = 20, replace = TRUE) # Gives an error
mylist[[1:length(mylist)]] <- sample(x = x, size = 20, replace = TRUE) # Does not give the desired result
mylist[1:length(mylist)] <- sample(x = x, size = 20, replace = TRUE) # Gives the same undesired result as the previous line of code
mylist[] <- sample(x = x, size = 20, replace = TRUE) # Gives the same undesired result as the previous line of code
```

P.S. As explained above, the desired result is a list of 20 elements, which individually contains 20 numeric values. I can do it using a `for` loop, but I would like to become a better R user and use vectorized operations as much as possible.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: [I'm posting here just to avoid chatting in Aaron's answer]. If I use your `x` and Aaron's code and run `identical(unname(mylist), lapply(seq(20, length(foo), 20), function(x) foo[(x-19):x]))`, I get `[1] TRUE`. I can't think of something that interferes with giving the correct result.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you're using `replace=TRUE` you could also generate all 400 at once and then split them up.  If you were doing this many times, this probably would be faster than `replicate`.  For only 20 times, the speed difference won't matter hardly at all and tje code using `replicate` is perhaps easier to read and understand and so might be preferred for that reason.

```
foo <- sample(x = x, size = 20*20, replace = TRUE)
mylist <- split(foo, rep(1:20, each=20))
```

Alternatively, you could split them by converting to a data frame first.  Not sure which would be faster.

```
mylist <- as.list(as.data.frame(matrix(foo, ncol=20)))
```

Comment: You are very right. I benchmarked the three methods: `replicate`, `split` and `matrix` and `split` came out on top closely followed by `matrix`. Also, you should edit your last line of code and change `nrow` to `ncol` since my desired list has 20 columns. `nrow` works in this case because there are 400 elements, but just for the sake of correctness. Thank you very much.

Comment: Fixed.  Also, for future readers, it's quite possible that with different sizes of matrices and amounts of replications timings will vary.  The details of your own situation will likely matter, including the need for readability.

Comment: @SavedByJESUS, too: Maybe `lapply(seq(20, length(foo), 20), function(x) foo[(x-19):x])` is faster than `split`?

Comment: @alexis_laz You are right!!! Using lapply is significantly faster. However, your piece of code does not give me the desired result, which is a list of 20 elements containing 20 numbers each.

Comment: It does here; what do you get instead?

Answer (score 5):

Maybe `replicate` is what you're looking for.

```
mylist <- replicate(20, sample(x = x, size = 20, replace = TRUE), simplify=FALSE)
names(mylist) <- paste0("element", 1:20, sep = "")
```

Note that there is no need to first create a list, `replicate` will do it for you.

Comment: Wow! Should I conclude that even the fact that I created an empty list that would get the values is a loop-y way of thinking?